# C++ numbers aren't rounding correctly

Tags: c++

I am new to Stack Overflow, and programming in general. I am in a few classes for programming C++ and have come across an assignment I am having a bit of trouble with. This program is supposed to take fahrenheit and convert it to celsius. I have seen other programs, but could not find a duplicate to my particular problem. This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fahrenheit;
    cout << "Please enter Fahrenheit degrees: ";
    cin >> fahrenheit;
    int celsius = 5.0 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
    cout << "Celsius: " << celsius << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So this is working great on 4 of the 5 tests that are run. It rounds 22.22 to 22 and 4.44 to 4 like it should, but when 0 F is put in, it rounds -17.77 to -17 instead of -18. I have been researching for about an hour and would love some help! Thank you.

Comment: Does C++ always round down? If so, how would I get it to round to -18? The tests I am running against, that is the only one that fails. It expects the program to say -18, but mine is saying -17.

Comment: Because converting a float or double **truncates** it by default. To **round** it, use a library function that  does that (Google it).

Comment: @Majora320 There are many kinds of rounding, actually: "towards zero" (also called "truncating", yes), "towards minus infinity" (also called "rounding down"), "towards plus infinity" (also called "rounding up"), "towards infinity" (it's basically "away from zero"), and "to nearest integer" (default meaning? sometimes). And "to nearest integer" methods differ in how they round `n+0.5` fractions.

Comment: There is no rounding here. Only integer truncation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers round down implicitly, as do casts to integer types.

Most likely, using a `float` in place of an `int` would give the most sane results:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fahrenheit;
    cout << "Please enter Fahrenheit degrees: ";
    cin >> fahrenheit;
    float celsius = 5.0 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
    cout << "Celsius: " << celsius << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To get normal-looking output (fixed-point like "14.25", not scientific with e notation), pass [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) to cout before printing the floating point. You can also use [`cout.precision()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) to set the number of digits you would like in the output.

---

If for some other reason you need an int, use [`std::round()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) around the right hand of the expression.

Comment: Use `double`, not `float`.

Comment: @Majora320 Float would almost certainly be sufficient for what he is doing. The choice between either would really be contextual.

Comment: I tried that before, and all of the answers display all the decimals, where they need to be rounded. I tried using cout.precision(0) but then my answers turn to e+ answers.

Comment: @EthanAdams That sounds like a separate question with perhaps a more interesting answer. But in this case, the rounding is not "wrong" - you are seeing what is supposed to happen with integers.

Comment: @EthanAdams This is probably the other thing you need to get what you expect: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/ . But I'm wondering why you'd get e-format floats in the first place, unless they were tiny/huge.

Comment: Just adding cout.precision(0); before int fahrenheit does this - when I put 72 for F, it comes out with 2e+01 as the answer for C, - 40 comes out -4e+01, 32 comes out 0, 40 comes out 4, and 0 comes out -2e+01. The exact same answers come when I change cout.precision(0) to (1)

Comment: If the number of digits needed to express the answer is less than precision, it *has* to use scientific notation. For example: how would you display 0.01 with 1 digit? it has to be 1e-2. Use std::fixed.

Comment: Integers don't round at all. They truncate.

Comment: @EJP Which is identical in all but tenuously terminology to rounding down. I suppose you could argue floor does not round down, but that is an unhelpful quibble to someone having issues with the basic concept.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::round()` instead of relying on the implicit conversion from `double` to `int`. Either that, or do not use conversion at all, show the temperature as a `double`.

**EDIT:** As others already pointed out, implicit conversion will not **round** but **truncate** the number instead (simply cut off everything after the decimal point).

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler converts a floating point number to an integer, it doesn't round, it *truncates*. I.e. it simply cuts of the digits after the decimal point. So your program behaves as it is programmed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 3.99;
int y = std::round(3.99);
std::cout 
   << "x = " << x << std::endl
   << "y = " << y << std::endl
   ;

--> 
x = 3
y = 4
```

C/C++ is not doing floating point round when `static_cast<int>`-ing a float to an int. If you want to round, you need to call library function `std::round()`